# Swift 3.0 Dynamically Change Font of a Label

Tags: swift, label, font-size

I am using a label to display text that the user has entered so the length of the label is variable. I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically change the font size of my text. Currently, I have constraint the vertical length of the label to 120, and checked off the "Automatically Adjust Font" in the Attributes Inspector but it doesn't scale it like I want. Not sure whether this is a programmatic or design method to do this.

Here's an example of the text being cut off:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try, eg:

```
autoshrink -> minimum font scale -> 0.7
```

[image]

Comment: This helps make it smaller, but it doesn't fit the whole text in the label. I even changed the number of lines to 0 for it to wrap into 2 lines and it still didn't help it fit.

Comment: does the label have a trailing constraint?

Comment: @Kevin instead of 0.7 you can try a smaller number. Ex 0.1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below;

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
yourLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.7;
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```